# Converting this cURL for Guzzle Post

Tags: php, curl

How to convert this follow cURL to Guzzle?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); // new
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $return;
```

I try this way. But doesn't work:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);

return $response;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Well, the API return an error, because the data is an array with some parameters to perfom an action, in this case above, create a charge. But for some reason, the API doesn't receive this data when I change to Guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your data as `json` option, Guzzle will encode this array as JSON and send JSON in request body. Use `form_params` instead of `json`.